# quick and dirty binary xor function

Tags: python, hash, binary

[image: the basic function i am trying to do]Hey me again o'merciless stack overflow gods.

I'm just looking for a way to get started on a simple xor hash function. I'm a tad prevented from accessing my usual sources as the Ethernet cable has been mysteriously disconnected from the router upstairs (again). I digress.

What I need to do is be able to fold ten bits against the next ten bits from a string of binary and `xor` them against each other. So I'm thinking
psuedocode

```
Raw input = (binary string or S)
Def function xor:
    Find Len of s
    Loop
        [0:9], [10:19] = xorcheck
        Loop 
            Xor [0:] & [10]
        Return result 
    [0 +1:] & [10 + 1:]
Return loop to xorcheck and store the.returned result.            
                       Variable hash ,maybe)
If second [:] return "none"
Divide Len by ten,
If true add "1000000000"
Else Add 0
Check if Len is / 10
if true print hash
Else add 0, check Len /10
```

Basically its light python script that will create a hash out of binary does. There are a few examples on here that I've looked at but they do far too much, like out put to hex. All I really need is function xor the binary string and output the result and a way to pad the whole string so the number of characters is a multiple of ten.

I apologize for the poor quality of question as I am now using my tiny smartphone for research :'(

## EDIT Update

I've edited Inspector's code as

```
   my_text = raw_input ()
''.join(bin(ascii)[2:] for ascii in [ord(char) for char in my_text])
def myHash(binary_encoded_ascii):
    answer = 0
    binstr = binary_encoded_ascii + '1'
    binstr += '0'*(20 - (len(bitstr) %20))
    for i in range(len(binstr)/20):
        s = binstr[20*i:20*(i+1)]
        s1,s2 = s[:10], s[10:]
        total += int(s1, 2) ^ int(s2, 2)
        return total
    print total
```

It would seem that it asks for text, but no values are printed. How can I get it to output the result so i can see if it actually is doing anything.

Comment: This a formatotastrophe I apologise

Comment: Learn the way of the backtick, and never fail to enter code again!

Comment: Backtick? Please enlighten me

Comment: input the codes between backticks ("`". Left of the '1' key)

Comment: Well, unless you're on a phone...then it's under some symbol keyboard menu somewhere :)

Comment: Also, `hash` is a pretty decent binary hash function, built in to Python :)

Comment: I tried to format your pseudocode. Please proof-read

Comment: Thank you very much & yes nneon I was on my phone. There's no formatting available there. I tried to indent manually (a nightmare) Apparently my switch is dead. Back on the PC now thank god.

Thank you very much inspector.

Comment: Ah I understand what you mean by backtick now. I'd never knew it was a specific punctuation um, thing.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your assignment question:

First, you need to convert your text into the binary encoding for the ascii values of its characters:

```
''.join(bin(ascii)[2:] for ascii in [ord(char) for char in my_text])
```

This gives you the binary encoded ascii values for all characters in your text, which you can then pass on to your hash function

```
def myHash(binary_encoded_ascii):
    answer = 0
    binstr = binary_encoded_ascii + '1'
    binstr += '0'*(20 - (len(bitstr) %20))
    for i in range(len(binstr)/20):
        s = binstr[20*i:20*(i+1)]
        s1,s2 = s[:10], s[10:]
        answer += int(s1, 2) ^ int(s2, 2)
    return answer
```

Comment: I'm just having a look at the code now, & it returns a "return outside function xorfunction line 7" I'm going to fiddle with it a bit.

So basically what i need it to do is xor each bit from from a ten bit block of binary against the corresponding bit frmo the next ten bit block.

Thereafter the whole string needs to be padded so it's divisible by ten. But it needs to be padded by at least one bit. It's a simple hash but that's what the assignment question demands.

Comment: The `return` bug is fixed. If you can post a link to the algorithm that must be implemented, I can take a look. Essentially, what does "the next 10 bit block" mean? If I have the string `abcdefghijklmnopqrst`, then are the 10-bit blocks `"abcdefghij" and "klmnopqrst"` or something else?

Comment: No longer returns an error, but also returns no value! ^^ It doesn't like the raw input being inside the function so I moved to before the function call so the input would be set as a global variable (is that the right term) ... but I think I might need to change how/where it returns what it finds in the loop.

Comment: okay so for example I'll input "‎1111010111 1100111001 1010010110 1100100011 0000010011 0011011001 1111100010 1111110100 1010011111 1101110101 1010111010 0111101110 1101010011 0010000001" and it needs to exclusive OR "‎1111010111" against "1100111001", and so on and so forth.

These values then need to be stored and output.

Comment: @Anaryl: which version of python are you using? py2k should not care about the placement of `raw_input`. Also, if you put the `raw_input` outside the function, you may as well pass it as a parameter

Comment: 2.7.2. As it's just a homework question it can be passed in either as raw input or as a parameter. It's not important. Just the XOR'ing function matters.

Comment: I still don't understand the 10-bit blocks. You provided 14 10-bit strings

Comment: The question is "The "Binary XOR (10)" hash works as follows. Suppose the input into the function is text, in the form of ascii characters.
This input can be represented by a sequence of 0s and 1s. Note the space character has an ascii representation also.
This sequence of bits is padded by appending 1000  0 so that the total number of bits is a multiple of 10. The input is
padded with a minimum of one bit. To compute the hash, the first 10 bits are XORed with the next ten bits, and so on
until the end of the (padded) message. The final XOR gives the hash of the message."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17798/discussion-between-inspectorg4dget-and-anaryl)